# Track inputs and toggle class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

What I am trying to achieve is track 20 inputs, if one is filled I want to add a class to a parent div of this input, if it becomes empty after I want the class to remove itself from the parent. This code does what I want when I run it in the console, how can I improve it so it can track the inputs and toggle the class?

```
$('.input').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    if ($input.val()) {
        var $parent = $input.closest('.card');
        $parent.addClass('colored')
    }
});
```

Comment: did any anwser helped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers, this is what worked for me after trying all the solutions. Hope it helps someone else.

```
function checkInputs() {
    $('.input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ""){
           $(this).parent().parent('.unit-card').removeClass('filled'); 
        } else {
           $(this).parent().parent('.unit-card').addClass('filled');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event to do so. For inputs, jQuery has the `input` event that fires every time the value of an input changes.

```
$(".input").on("input", function () {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0)
        $(this).closest('.card').removeClass("colored");
    else
        $(this).closest('.card').addClass("colored");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks for values at the initial run. You would need to attach events `copy`, `paste`, `change`, `keypress`, `keydown`, `keyup` and `input`. See example:

```js
$('input').on('copy paste keydown keyup keypress change input', function(){

  var $input = $(this);

  if( $input.val() == '' ){
     $input.parent('.form-group').addClass('empty');
  } else {
     $input.parent('.form-group').removeClass('empty');
  }

});
```

```css
.form-group {
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
.form-group.empty > input {
   border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input name="address" type="text" placeholder="address"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type='text']").on("keyup",function(){

if($(this).val()!="")
{
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
}else{
$(this).parent().removeClass("active");
}

})
```

```css
.active{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="text" >
</div>
```

Comment: I also tried the onchage first but onchange on inputs require to focus out from the input. So change it with keyup or keydown will be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet [**Here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=f7684323b4bd9241fd6bdaeab019291d). An `keyup()` function and an if check done them all.